# How to transfer/stream big data from/to child processes in node.js without using the blocking stdio?

Tags: node.js, stream, child-process

I have a bunch of (child)processes in node.js that need to transfer large amounts of data.

When I read the manual it says the the stdio and ipc inferface between them are blocking, so that won't do.

I'm looking into using file descriptors but I cannot find a way to stream from them (see my other more specific question [How to stream to/from a file descriptor in node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582183/how-to-stream-to-from-a-file-descriptor-in-node))

I think I might use a net socket, but I fear that has unwanted overhead.

I also see this but it not the same (and has no answers: [How to send huge amounts of data from child process to parent process in a non-blocking way in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450257/how-to-send-huge-amounts-of-data-from-child-process-to-parent-process-in-a-non-b))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to work: when spawning the child process you can pass options for `stdio` and setup a pipe to stream data.

The trick is to add an additional element, and set it to 'pipe'.

In the **parent** process stream to `child.stdio[3]`.

```
var opts = {
    stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr, 'pipe']
};
var child = child_process.spawn('node', ['./child.js'], opts);

// send data
mySource.pipe(child.stdio[3]);

//read data
child.stdio[3].pipe(myHandler);
```

In de **child** open stream for file descriptor 3.

```
// read from it
var readable = fs.createReadStream(null, {fd: 3});

// write to it
var writable = fs.createWriteStream(null, {fd: 3});
```

Note that not every stream you get from npm works correctly, I tried `JSONStream.stringify()` but it created errors, but it worked after I piped it via `through2`. (no idea why that is).

Edit: some observations: it seems the pipe is not always Duplex stream, so you might need two pipes. And there is something weird going on where in one case it only works if I also have a ipc channel, so 6 total: [stdin, stdout, stderr, pipe, pipe, ipc].

Comment: With regard to your edit: I could be wrong (not familiar with the Node code base), but [it seems](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v4.x/lib/internal/child_process.js#L313) that `stdin` is the only pipe guaranteed to be writable from the parent process.