# How does requset.get().pipe() works?

Tags: node.js, request

If I use

```
request.get(imageUrl).pipe(resposne)
```

then, does it return response with all data received from `request.get()` including headers and all the other data ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the .pipe() perform a memcpy in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110911/does-the-pipe-perform-a-memcpy-in-node-js)

Comment: i answered a similar question long ago with quite some details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110911/does-the-pipe-perform-a-memcpy-in-node-js/35178495#35178495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [request module](https://github.com/request/request#streaming).

The request is a readable stream (That's why you can use the `pipe()` function). The readable data in stream here is the body of HTTP response.

To get the headers and status code as well, you can listen to events:

```
request
  .get('http://example.com/img.png')
  .on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode) // 200
    console.log(response.headers['content-type']) // 'image/png'
  })
  .pipe(request.put('http://example.com/img.png'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You will use pipe when you want to stream a response.

For example

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

Or

```
request.get('http://google.com/img.png').pipe(request.put('https://xxxe.com/img.png)
```

You don't need to use pipe in your case as response.get will also contain all information.