# How to get process.stdio from node.js script?

Tags: node.js

sorry if I am not descriptive enough, If I need to be please let me know.

I'm trying to have one node.js script use `child_process.spawn()` on another node.js script. I am successfully able to make it execute but I am unable to retrieve data from pipes other than stdin, stdout, and stderr.

When I do a `spawn()` command I have the option of accessing "stdio" but I don't have that option with `process`. `process.stdio` is undefined.

When I `spawn()` an ffmpeg process I can easily get data from more than the 3 default pipes.

So, my question is : How can I get access to more pipes from a regular node.js script?

Essentially I would like to access things like `process.stdio[1]` instead of `process.stdout` because then I can use `process.stdio` with numbers a lot higher than `2`.

any help is appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [child process docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_stdio) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582213/how-to-transfer-stream-big-data-from-to-child-processes-in-node-js-without-using/24583564#24583564) you can do this by creating a write stream to `{ fd: 3 }`:

**On parent:**

```
const opts = {
    stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']
};
const child = child_process.spawn('node', ['./child.js'], opts);

//read data
child.stdio[3].pipe(myHandler);
//or
child.stdio[3].on('data', data => {
  //handle data
});
```

**On child:**

```
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(null, {fd: 3});
dataStream.pipe(writeStream);
//or write data chunks directly
writeStream.write(data);
```

This is untested, but should work OK.

Comment: i love you, you saved me hours of my life. sincerely, thank you so much. If you are a Shinobi user, contact me on Discord and ill hook you up a free lifetime subscription key. thank you!!!