# Are the extra stdio streams in node.js child_process.spawn blocking?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, nonblocking

When creating a child process using spawn() you can pass options to create multiple streams via the `options.stdio` argument. after the standard 3 (stdin, stdout, stderr) you can pass extra streams and pipes, which will be file descriptor in the child process. Then you can use a fs.createRead/WriteStream to access those.

See http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

```
var opts = {
    stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr, 'pipe']
};
var child = child_process.spawn('node', ['./child.js'], opts);
```

But the docs are not really clear on where these pipes are blocking. I know stdin/stdout/stderr are blocking, but what about the `'pipe'`'s?

In one part they say:

> "Please note that the send() method on both the parent and child are
>   synchronous - sending large chunks of data is not advised (pipes can
>   be used instead, see child_process.spawn"

But elsewhere they say:

> process.stderr and process.stdout are unlike other streams in Node in
>   that writes to them are usually blocking.
>
> ```
> They are blocking in the case that they refer to regular files or TTY file descriptors.
> In the case they refer to pipes:
>     They are blocking in Linux/Unix.
>     They are non-blocking like other streams in Windows.
> ```

Can anybody clarify this? Are pipes blocking on Linux?

I need to transfer large amounts of data without blocking my worker processes.

Related:

- [How to send huge amounts of data from child process to parent process in a non-blocking way in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450257/how-to-send-huge-amounts-of-data-from-child-process-to-parent-process-in-a-non-b)
- [How to transfer/stream big data from/to child processes in node.js without using the blocking stdio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582213/how-to-transfer-stream-big-data-from-to-child-processes-in-node-js-without-using/24583564#24583564)

Comment: did y finally got a working prototype up which satisfies y? y had a bunch of questions about it, what did it for you, how about using standard stdin/out, why especially nonblocking. Would be great to have y answer officially on y question